# Is the projection from $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ $f(m, n) = (m + n,m − n)$ injective and how to prove it

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I tried to solve it using linear span, but that seems to be a wrong approach.

Edit: and surjective

Comment: Do you know what a kernel is?

Comment: @anon I do. This is from a discrete mathematics class though, not linear algebra.

Comment: Re: surjective or not. Test a few points $m,n$. Do you notice anything about the resulting coordinates? (Think in terms of even/odd.)

Comment: @Grant That doesn't mean you can't use ideas from linear algebra though (although you have to be careful that this is over $\mathbb{Z}$, so really you would be doing group theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f(a_1, b_1) = f(a_2, b_2)$. Then by definition of $f$ we have
$$
(a_1 + b_1, a_1 - b_1) = (a_2 + b_2, a_2 - b_2)
$$
This becomes two equations of integers:
$$
\begin{cases}a_1 + b_1 = a_2 + b_2 \\ a_1 - b_1 = a_2 - b_2\end{cases}
$$ Adding the equations makes it clear that $2a_1 = 2a_2$, and subtracting them shows that $2b_1 = 2b_2$. Thus we must have $(a_1, b_1) = (a_2, b_2)$ and the function is injective.

For surjectivity, note that in $f(a, b) = (a + b, a - b)$, the first and second element have the *same* parity (they're either both even or both odd). Thus there is no $(a, b) \in \Bbb Z^2$ such that, for instance, $f(a, b) = (2, 3)$, since $2$ and $3$ have *opposite* parity. So $f$ is *not* surjective.

PS. If $f$ is seen as a function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$ instead, with the same definition, the injectivity proof still holds, and a similar procedure as in that proof reveals that $f(\frac{5}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) = (2, 3)$. Since the function is injective, there are no other points that maps to $(2, 3)$, so it cannot be done with integer coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Its matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$, which is invertible as a *real* matrix (its determinant is $-2$). Therefore it is injective $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$. If you find two pairs of *integers* that map to the same image, they are in particular also pairs of real numbers, so that would contradict being injective $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$

Comment: Thank you. Would you please add if it is surjective?

Comment: @Grant: It's not -- the components of the result are either both odd or both even.

Answer (score 1):

the kernel of $f$ is clearly just $(0,0)$ so $f$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please add if it is surjective?

Comment: i think its not surjective e.g. there are no elements that map to $(a,-a)$ ($a \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: @Robert.Sie $f(0, a)$

Comment: ok i missed that, but Arthur already gave a good explanation.